# Updating MySQL fields only when other information in the row changes

Tags: mysql

I have a problem where I would like a field to work in a similar way to the timestamp type field, where it only gets updated on an update if there are other changes to the record.

I am using php to update a mysql database with myisam tables.

Take the following example table which has one row with the following fields;-

```
UNIQUEID : 1
TITLE    : Example
AMENDAT  : (timestamp)
AMENDBY  : Andy
```

I have some code which handles maintenance on the table. The update to the table uses (for example) the following statement ;-

```
update example set TITLE="New Title",AMENDBY="Andy" where UNIQUEID=1 ;
```

This statement works fine and updates the row including the AMENDAT timestamp field.

If a different user makes the same change;-

```
update example set TITLE="New Title",AMENDBY="Bob" where UNIQUEID=1 ;
```

Again, everything works as expected.

But, it is possible that the update statement may be called when no changes have been made to any of the columns in the statement (this is possible in the real world because I have a large number of fields in the table which are all updated at once and I do not wish to code a check on the before and after values of the fields - I just let the update take the strain);-

```
update example set TITLE="Example",AMENDBY="Andy" where UNIQUEID=1 ;
```

In this case, MySQL decides that nothing need be done, so it does not update the AMENDAT timestamp (all good so far).

But if another user does the same thing;-

```
update example set TITLE="Example",AMENDBY="Bob" where UNIQUEID=1 ;
```

Then the row is updated due to the change in the AMENDBY field. So even though the actual data has not changed, the amendment details have (which is not good for my amendment tracking).

My current work around for this problem is to use the following statement for updates;-

```
update example set TITLE="XYZ",AMENDBY="XYZ",AMENDAT=NULL where UNIQUEID=123 ;
```

This forces an update every time, so the amendment details will reflect the last user to save the record whether or not they made any changes. Obviously this is not ideal.

Is there any way of making the AMENDBY field update only when there are changes to other fields on the record, much like the default functioning of a timestamp type field?

I realise this problem is easily solved by making two separate calls to MySQL, one to do the update and check from the return (number of records updated) whether to make a second call to update the amendment details, but this is a messy and not very elegant solution.

Bear in mind that I have a large number of tables which are set up in the same way, each has an arbitrary number of fields, so I don't want a solution which requires an enormous call to MySQL which includes an if statement for every field which may or may not be updated.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are trying to do can be achieved with a TRIGGER with timing AFTER on the UPDATE event. Triggers can be tricky though, use them with extra caution. Also bear in mind, that if the trigger statement fails for some reason the actual UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE fails too.